# What is the type of a type signature?

Tags: reference-request, type-theory, haskell

For example, using [GHCi](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/GHCi),

```
ghci> f x = x + 1
ghci> :t f
f :: Num a => a -> a
```

What is the type of the [type signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) `f :: Num a => a -> a`?

---

**Motivation**

I first encountered this question at work. Since I do **not** want to leak any information pertaining to my employment, I shall present a *toy* project instead.

Suppose that I have a list of fruits that I want to buy at a farmers' market, e.g.,

| Fruits | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 5 |
| Orange | 4 |

Suppose that I save this list in a CSV file.  When reading the CSV file, I would like to obtain a data structure in which the names of the fruits are not of type `String` but, rather, values of, say, the following [sum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

```
data Fruit = Apple | Coconut | Mango | Orange | Peach | Pear deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I would like to have a [type signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) as an input to the function that reads the CSV file — say, something that specifies that `Fruits :: Fruit` and `Quantity :: Integer`. However, what is the type of a [type signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature)?

Please do note that this is **not** a question on how to write the aforementioned function in [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell).  Here, [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell) is used merely for the sake of clarity and succinctness. I am looking for references — books, theses, papers, technical reports, etc.